# Wireless and Wired Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, wired-networking

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but my office has two networks, the corporate (hardwired) and the guest (wireless). I need to be connected to the corporate network to access all of our internal applications, but the corp network blocks streaming services. Our guest network, however, does not block streaming. When I'm plugged in I'm connected to the corporate network, but I can also connect to the guest wireless while plugged in. So it looks like I can be connected to both simultaneously. So I was wondering, is there a way to direct all blocked traffic through our guest network, and all other traffic through the corporate network.

This is obviously to satisfy my own personally curiosity and, in no way, an attempt to circumvent our companies security policy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access certain servers through your wireless network or to access just anything that isn't accessible from the wired through wireless?

Comment: @RadialApps The latter. I want it to default to with wired, and if its blocked, then fail over to the wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done at the level of IP routing or some "application level" traffic shaping

Depending on the operating system that you're using there will be differences on how to do this.

for example in GNU/Linux you'll have 2 interfaces:

```
    /sbin/ifconfig
    (..)
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa
    (..)
    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:02:dd:cc:bb:aa  

    /sbin/route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref     Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

as you can see all traffic (0.0.0.0) goes thru eth0

So here is how to add an specific host (8.8.8.8 in this case) via a separate gw or interface
but if you do:

```
   sudo route add -host 8.8.8.8 gw 192.168.1.2  wlan0
   /sbin/route -n
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
   8.8.8.8         192.168.1.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

you just have to know the IP of the host you want and the gateway of the wlan0 network (which is easy if you have connectivity)

Comment: BTW, connecting to both networks simultaneously would enable your PC to be used as a bridge, circumventing the corporate firewall. IT department might, understandably, look at this as a **very bad** thing.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik That's not the case unless you specifically set your computer up as a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

As answered before, if you know the subnets or IP address ranges of the services you want to connect to using wireless, you can create specific routes to said services.

The answer above is for Linux. For Windows it is a little different.
You can use the command "route" ("route add, route change" etc.), but Windows has the nasty habit of changing the ID of its wireless adapters. And you need the ID of the adapter to change or add a route...

I have developed a small Windows utility that can get this Wireless adapter ID and I can teach you how to use a batch file to 
- get the id of the WiFi card
- change the route (including the default route).
I used to do that in a corporate environment too, for reasons different than yours: needed to access my own subnets, but the corporate environment had a configuration that would route, by default, all the packets through its gateway and said gateway didn't know my own lab/isolated subnets...

You can also do it another (and tricky) way :
You would just have to change the metric assigned to the gateway used by your wireless card and/or your wired card.
The lower metric, the higher priority!

Search for "change metric of network interface" for your OS. Set the WiFi metric to, lets' say, 10, and the Wired metric to 20. You would have to specify not to use automatic metric.

Explanation:
You have two network cards, so you have two different default gateways, each one for one network card. The OS sends packets to unknown network routes through the interface that has the lowest metric for the default gateway.

All packets to known routes are sent through the interface that "knows" the routes, so it is very likely that the routes to "internal/corporate" subnets have their own routes, "attached" to the wired interface. Thus, you would still be able to connect to the corporate resources and, at the same time, to the resources available on the WiFi network.

But beware, you may violate some company policy by doing so and you can potentially expose your computers (and other resources) to unwanted people or programs...